# How to solve $\int \frac{1}{3 + \cos(t)}dt$

Tags: calculus

I'm studying alone using class notes and there is a part I need to solve this integral $\int \frac{1}{3 + \cos(t)}dt$ . The notes suggest to substitute $t=\cos (2\arctan(u))$ but even so I'm not able to solve this yet. Can anyone help step-by-step how to solve this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

Comment: Hint: named functions like "cos" and "arctan" look better if you put a backslash in front like this: `\cos (t)`. I've edited to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\int\dfrac{1}{3+\cos t}\ dt$

Apply $u$ substitution $u=\tan\left(\dfrac t2\right)$, $du=\dfrac12\ dx \ \sec^2\left(\dfrac x2\right)$
$$=\int\dfrac{1}{u^2+2}\ du$$

Now again apply substitution $u=\sqrt{2}v$
$$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\dfrac{1}{v^2+1} \ dv=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan(v)$$

Comment: Sorry, but can you do it step-by-step?

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro is it clear now?

Comment: The problem is when I use $t=2arctan (u) $ the integral becomes so complicated to simplify. Then $ \frac {1}{1+cos (2arctan (u))} = \frac {1}{3+ \frac {1}{(1 +u^{2})^{1/2}}}...$

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro see my above answer. I explained everything.

Comment: Now it's much better!!! Thank you for your reply!